# Does fragment call the onCreate method of parent activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity with a viewPager inside of it, and a static ArrayList of integers that I am shuffling using `Collections.shuffle(list)` in the activity's onCreate method, this viewPager's fragments are using the ArrayList in parent activity.

The problem is that whenever a new fragment instantiated of the viewPager the onCreate method of parent activity is called, and I don't want that to happen because I want the list to have the same data in all fragments and not reshuffled. Do fragments call the onCreate method of their parent activities everytime there is a new instance? if Yes how can I work around this to keep the list from shuffling every time?

**CODE:**

Activity Code:

```
public static final ArrayList<Integer> IDs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        IDs.add(0);
        IDs.add(1);
        IDs.add(2);

        Collections.shuffle(IDs);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkthrough);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Fragment Code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = (View) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_walkthrough, container, false);

        final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.walkthrough_images);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        if (page == 0) {
            imageView.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(Walkthrough.IDs.get(0), 0));
        } else if (page == 2) {
            imageView.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(Walkthrough.IDs.get(1), 0));
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(Walkthrough.IDs.get(2), 0));
        }

        return v;

    }
```

Now I want the ArrayList "IDs" to always have the same data and order when ever I instantiate a new fragment but it is not working, every time I create a new fragment the method onCreate gets recalled and a reshuffle happens!

Comment: Please, show your code.

Comment: fragments have their own life cycle. activity is only used as container and  launch any fragment.

Comment: How have you determined that `onCreate()` is being called multiple times? And what does the `page` variable do in `onCreateView()` of your `Fragment`? Could you also include the code for your `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` in your question please?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are added to activity and therefore fragments get affected by activity.
Activity can cause calling any fragment callback method, but fragment can't

The lifecycle of the activity in which the fragment lives directly affects the lifecycle of the fragment.

For example, when the activity receives onPause(), each fragment in the activity receives onPause().

Fragments have a few extra lifecycle callbacks, however, that handle unique interaction with the activity in order to perform actions such as build and destroy the fragment's UI.
 These additional callback methods are like  onAttach(), onCreateView(), etc.

It'll clears the somewhat relation between fragment and activity.

Thanks

Comment: so why is the onCreate method of the activity is getting called multiple times?

Comment: I just added a counter to my log in the onCreate method of the parent activity, it is called 15 times!!!!!

Comment: i think your activity is restarting automatically, may be due to any memory, or android device problem.